# Does const on value different const on array

Tags: c++, c, arrays

It seems that const on array will cause the memory used to store the array mark read-only in memory. But why const on int won't do the same thing?

Code is here:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    const int vv = 10 ;
    int * p = (int *)&vv ;
    *p = 5 ; // work well

    const int aa[3] = {11, 12, 13} ;
    int * pp = (int *)&aa[1] ;
    *pp = 100 ; // EXC_BAD_ACCESS

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "work well" is really **undefined behaviour**, i.e. not work well.

Comment: If you're using gcc or clang, then you can have the compiler warn you of issues like these using the option `-Wcast-qual`

Comment: @MagnusReftel Apple LLVM... not warning

Comment: Many people get confused by this but C/C++ lets you do lots of silly things that result in undefined behavior. Generally there are reasons behind it, even though some are quite complex and/or might have lost some significance over the years. You just have to learn to be careful in those cases.

Comment: in C++, you should prefer `static_cast<int*>()` over `(int*)`. It would have issued a compiler failure whereas you thought it was working well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the first and the second, as stated in §7.1.6.1/4, results in *undefined behavior*:

> Except that any class member declared mutable (7.1.1) can be modified, any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior.

This is, in fact, one of those cases where a C++-style cast (like `static_cast`), except for `const_cast`, [would have warned you](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b9501a7507f3374).

In the C standard the same reference is made at §6.7.3/5:

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: If you didn't want C++ answers, why did you tag your question C++?

Comment: @kfsone I know every C++ programmer has the basic on c.

Answer (score 2):

Any attempt to modify data that is `const` results in *undefined behaviour* (UB). That means that your code might seem to "work well", but it cannot be relied on for anything.

Both your examples are UB.

Answer (score 2):

If you get a bad access on the second access it means your compiler doesn't copy the initializer list to `aa` but have `aa` point to the process's const data section (e.g. where the string literals are stored).

As others have pointed out, changing a const produces undefined behavior. In Visual Studio, your code will not produce any errors.

The problem surfaces when multiple references to the same const object (or array in C) occur. Changing one will change all of them and only in optimized builds. This sort of bug is hard to track.

Answer (score 1):

look ISO/IEC 9899 TC3 ->§6.7.3 part 5 there is said:

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined. If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

So I guess this is clear enough for C, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Your first part of code is pretty correct. You are modifying the value stored at location using its reference. This is defined behavior. The compiler checks this variable won't be on left side of an expression.

Use the following to keep value pointed by it to be constant.

```
const int * p = (int *)&vv
```